# ERROR NetworkError at send (./node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:281:19)

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am using angular 16. I am using angular/universal for server side rendering. I have a service named as translationService.

when I import this in app component,

```
 constructor(
    private translationService: TranslationService
  )
```

I am getting this error:

```
NetworkError
    at send (./node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:281:19)
    at observer (./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/http.mjs:2187:21)
    at _trySubscribe (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:41:25)
    at cb (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:35:31)
    at errorContext (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/errorContext.js:22:9)
    at subscribe (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:26:24)
    at onNext (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:17:63)
    at _next (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:33:21)
    at next (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:51:18)
    at <anonymous> (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/observable/innerFrom.js:120:28)
```

I don't have any idea about this error. kindly facilitate.

```
import { Injectable, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
// import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TranslationService implements AfterViewInit {
  public lang = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
  value: any;
  @ViewChild('body') body: any;

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    this.lang.next('en');
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {}
  changeLanguage(value: any) {
    this.translate.setDefaultLang(value);
    localStorage.setItem('lang', value);
    this.lang.next(value);
    this.value = value;

    if (value == 'ar') {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('direction', 'rtl');
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('overflow-x', 'hidden');
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('width', '101%');
    } else {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('direction', 'ltr');
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('width', '100%');
    }
  }
}
```

this is app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreService } from '../services/core.service';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import {
  TranslateModule,
  TranslateLoader,
  TranslateStore,
} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      defaultLanguage: 'en',
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [CoreService, TranslateStore],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run angular-app-for-ssr:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/angular-app-for-ssr/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run angular-app-for-ssr:server",
    "prerender": "ng run angular-app-for-ssr:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^16.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "8.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  
}
```

I am trying to render my app on server side. My application is running absolutly fine on client side. but when i tried ssr it gives me network error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

The problem arose because on the node.js server, translation files were not being loaded successfully. The file URLs were not recognized and had the wrong protocol.  On the browser side, however, everything was fine as we were using TranslateHttpLoader.

To correct this problem, I had to create a special loader that loads translation files as typescript constants. This allows the node.js server to understand this loading.
Here is the discussion were I found this solution: https://gist.github.com/ocombe/593d21598d988bf6a8609ba5fc00b67e?permalink_comment_id=2110044

Here is the description of the solution in the discussion:
[image]